# After entering a text in the input of PysimpleGUI, how do I put the cursor to the end of the input text automatically?

Tags: python, input, window, pysimplegui

I have created a pysimplegui window, like the following:
[image]

Now, as I input a text, the input text is shown as the following:
[image]

But I want the cursor to be located to the right of the text automatically as the text is entered, like the following:
[image]

This is my code for the window:

```
# Creating the GUI window.

sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a touch of color

# All the stuff inside your window.
lengthOfInputBar = 40   # Length of the bar where inputs are entered.
layout = [ [sg.Text(text='Valgrind Message .txt File Location'), 
            sg.Input(default_text='', size=(lengthOfInputBar, 1), 
                     enable_events=True, key='-VALGRIND_OUTPUT_TXT_INP-'), 
            sg.FileBrowse(file_types=[('TXT (*.txt)', '*.txt')])] ]
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no existing method to view/move cursor to end of `sg.Input`.

- Call tkinter method `xview_moveto(f)` to positions the text in the `sg.Input`, the f argument must be in the range [0,1], where 0 means the left end of the text and 1 the right end.
- Call tkinter method `icursor(index) to set the insertion cursor just before the character at the given index,` end` for end of line.

Example Code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg


sg.theme('DarkAmber')

lengthOfInputBar = 40
layout = [
    [sg.Text(text='Valgrind Message .txt File Location'),
     sg.Input(default_text='', size=(lengthOfInputBar, 1), enable_events=True, key='-VALGRIND_OUTPUT_TXT_INP-'),
     sg.FileBrowse(file_types=[('TXT (*.txt)', '*.txt')])],
]
window = sg.Window('Songs list', layout, finalize=True)
entry = window['-VALGRIND_OUTPUT_TXT_INP-'].Widget

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == '-VALGRIND_OUTPUT_TXT_INP-':
        entry.xview_moveto(1)       # View end
        entry.icursor('end')        # Move cursor to end

window.close()
```